# Intersection of two divisors on a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I encountered a question when I was trying to read the proof of the negativity lemma in the minimal model theory. I summerize it as follow:

> Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a projective birational morphism between surfaces and $D=D^+-D^-$ a Cartier divisor on $X$ where $-D$ is nef over Y$ and D^+$, $D^-\ge 0$ having no common components and $D^-\neq 0$. Assume that Supp$D^-\subseteq$ Exc$f$(i.e., the negative part of $D$ is contracted to points on $Y$).
>
> Let $E\ge 0$ be an exceptional divisor on $X$ s.t. Supp$E=$ Exc$f$ and $E$ is anti-nef but not numerically trivial/$Y$. Assume that $m$ is the smallest non-negative number s.t.  $D+mE\ge 0$. Then there must be some component $C$ of $D^-$ s.t. $D+mE$ has coefficient $0$ at $C$. Now assume that $D+mE>0$. Then, there is a component $C$ of $D^-$ s.t. $C$ intersects $Supp(D+mE)$.

The last sentence confuses me. It seems to me that the statement is trying to say that any component of $D^-$ intersects some components of $D^+$. I guess the phenomenon has something to do with that $f$ has connected fibers? But I don't know how to understand it.

Comment: I don't think this is right. Take $f$ the blow up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at a point. Take a line not passing through the point. The strict transform of this line will not intersect the exceptional divisor.

Comment: @userunknown Sorry I forgot to mention that $E$ is anti-nef but not numerically trivial/$Y$ and $−D$ is nef$/Y$. Does that help?